# StructureMap - Ability to replace an assembly at runtime

Tags: c#, assemblies, ioc-container, structuremap, appdomain

Example:

Console application:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var calculator = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ICalculator>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(calculator.Calculate(10, 5));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Assembly "Interface":

```
public interface ICalculator
{
    int Calculate(int a, int b);
}
```

Assembly "Implemenation":

```
internal class Calculator : ICalculator
{
    public int Calculate(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Assembly "Implemenation", this assembly shall replace the assembly above at runtime:

```
internal class Calculator : ICalculator
{
    public int Calculate(int a, int b)
    {
        return a * b;
    }
}
```

Assembly "Resolver"

```
For<ICalculator>().Use<Calculator>();
```

I want to replace the concrete implementation at runtime. This could be done by an UpdateService which just replace the old assembly "Implementation".

The problem I have is that the assembly "Implementation" is locked. I can't replace it.

What do I have to do to achieve this?

Is the IoC container responsible for my requirement or do I have to build my own infrastructure?

**EDIT:**

In a web environment you can easily replace an assembly. I did this already with success.

Comment: why -1? Thanks for not giving a comment!

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is you are trying to solve by replacing an assembly (or is it a set of registrations you want to replace?) at runtime?

Comment: I want to have the possiblity to update my application witout closing it. So i.e. I want to update my DAL, because there was a bug, but my application must still run.

Comment: I would strongly advice _not_ to do such a thing. This will hardly ever work and there are all sorts of problems that will come up. Please post a new question specific to this way of updating here at SO and ask whether this would be a good idea and what the problems are you can encounter.

Comment: @Steven I have opened a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554342/component-based-architecture-replacing-an-assembly-at-runtime

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you can only load an additional assembly.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173101%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> There is no way to unload an individual assembly without unloading all
>   of the application domains that contain it. Even if the assembly goes
>   out of scope, the actual assembly file will remain loaded until all
>   application domains that contain it are unloaded.

Comment: My described web scenario works, because of the IIS who comes into play as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has what you're looking for:

http://structuremap.net/structuremap/ChangingConfigurationAtRuntime.htm

Comment: I do not want to change my configuration. I really just want to replace an assembly at runtime. Just override with copy and paste an assembly at runtime.

Comment: The assembly is loaded into memory and locked at runtime, I'm afraid you aren't going to have any options as far as replacing the assembly. The version on the hard drive wouldn't matter anyway since it is already loaded and running from memory.