# Component based architecture: Replacing an assembly at runtime

Tags: c#, architecture, replace, assemblies, components

Is it a good idea to replace an assembly at runtime?
What problems can I encounter?

Original question: [StructureMap - Ability to replace an assembly at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505812/structuremap-ability-to-replace-an-assembly-at-runtime)

What is the difference in replacing an assembly at runtime within a web- and a non-web application?

Comment: The most obvious issue would be performance

Comment: @GertAnrold you are wrong. I already done this with a web application. Have a look at the http://codecampserver.codeplex.com/ site.

Comment: @MohamedAbed would you be so nice and give me more details?

Comment: In order for any framework, IoC container, or code by hand, to support replacing assembly at run time would either:

- Load these assemblies each in a separate app domain in order to be able to unload an assembly and load another instead (replace) .. this will lead to a performance and memory footpring implication because having separate appdomains has it's cost of marshaling and memory management.

- Replace the content of the assembly at run time in the IL level (interception) and that also will have huge cost in pefrormance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that IIS creates a new shadow copy each time you update a DLL. Hence you get a new AppDomain automatically when you add the new DLL.

WinForms etc doesn't do that magic for you and that's why it won't work.

Comment: this sounds interesting. As Mohamed Abed mentioned in his comment this would lead to a peformance and memory footpring implication. So is this a relevant or irrelevant performance issue?

Comment: In the scenario of a web application using IIS. 2nd question would be: How can I build this "magic" in non webapplications and what issues can I encounter?

Comment: Well, you don't update the DLL's often so I don't see any performance penalties. imho the same problem doesn't exist for client applications. Simply restart the application after updating the DLLs

Comment: What if I cant easily close my application, because it has to be run everytime. So what I still want to achieve is to replace an assembly(dll) at runtime. As I have understood you, there should be no problem.

Comment: JGauffin is right. IIS restarts the application for you, but since a web application is stateless, you most of the time won't notice much of this.

Answer (score 1):

If the code that runs against that assembly runs in a separate AppDomain and that you shut down the appdomain before doing the operation, you should have no problem.

Comment: Did you have a look at my original question?

Comment: Now I did, and I guess that since you are using ioc, your IOC container "references" the assembly which you then obviously can't replace..  Sorry